# Cannot execute code in some of Jupyiter ipython notebook cells

Tags: python, ipython, cell, jupyter-notebook

Any cells in Jupyter which have `In [*]` in front of them are not executing in Jupyter notebook. See image below:

[image]

I even restarted the kernel, without any improvement of the situation. Previous cells run without trouble. Every cell I added recently has the problem.

Comment: Why do you have lines that start that way?

Comment: @zondo, please see the added image. I didn't add those. Those were in front of each cell. I guess ln indicates line number

Comment: What is the console output of the Jupyter kernel? Can you run normal ipython?

Comment: there is no such notable output in the console.

Comment: Can you run ipython in a terminal? What about `jupyter console`? Is there anything the cells that have problems have in common - e.g. do they all start with a blank line like the picture in the question? Does the browser's JS console show any errors when this happens?

Comment: Thanks guys..   I did remove a  top blank line from one of the cells.  It runs after many restarts of the kernel. Oh God :)

Comment: @andy Did you resolve this problem? I'm facing it right now...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the following steps:

1. Close ipython notebook, and then reopen the file.
2. If 1 does not work, then restart the kernel and reopen the file.
3. If 2 does not work, then try whether things work fine on console. Type `ipython` and check whether your code statements work.
4. If 3 does not work, try reinstalling the scientific python distribution if you are using Anaconda or Enthought.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered same problem on my windows machine.Try [Jupyter with Anaconda on Windows will not run cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486586/jupyter-with-anaconda-on-windows-will-not-run-cells). Probably your antivirus program or your iis is blocking default 8888 port.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading tornado to 4.5.3 fixed my problem. with

```
pip - sudo python3.6 -m pip install tornado==4.5.3
conda - conda install tornado==4.5.3
```

use this for this bugs

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a lot of notebooks(tabs) open with running kernels in them. You can check this by clicking on this icon [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Z8F.png) on the left. There you see all the running kernels in all your open notebooks and shut them down.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1I5l.png)  This should solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).