# Why my code does'nt execute on ipython notebook?

Tags: python, command-line, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am totally new to jupyter notebook and I was trying to run a simple code and its not working.[image]

I typed print (1) and hit ctrl + enter, and then that asterisk mark appeared and thats pretty much it. there is a blinking "connected" in the console as well.

Command window looks like this:
[image]

Any tip regarding this would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486586/jupyter-with-anaconda-on-windows-will-not-run-cells

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, as Teemo pointed out all I had to do was use this,

C:\Python27\Scripts>jupyter notebook --port=8889

instead of,

C:\Python27\Scripts>jupyter notebook.

port 8889 , worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

using Jupyter on a VM, this was also for me the solution. Additionally, you can create a config file with:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

and search In your `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file for `c.NotebookApp.port = 8888` (and change the port to 8889)

so you don't have to manually add the port every time jupyter is called.

Comment: Please use code formatting to format code snippets and commands.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and changing the host port didn't solve anything. I finally had to uninstalled the jupyter network package. I installed it has well through "pip install", I'd suggest to uninstall it as well using and only  reinstalling it with the following through conda:

```
conda uninstall jupyter notebook 
pip uninstall jupyter 
pip3 uninstall jupyter
conda install jupyter notebook
```